# Pentaho error data truncate when insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I'm developing Pentaho job to get data from BigQuery and insert into SQL Server. The job is quite simple as you can see below but during insert to a SQL Server table process in thrown 'Data truncation' error. Then I checked max length for this column. It is just 64 while in database it is `nvarchar(500)`. Moreover that I want to know how is look like then for error records I log into text file. You can see it below. I've spent for 3 days with this problem but still not get an answer yet. Please do guide me.

What I have done so far

- String cut step to sub string
- String Operation step to trim
- put left function in `SELECT` statement
- put `REGEXP_REPLACE(uuid, ' ', '')` which remove spaces in `SELECT` statement.

All I have done getting the same error.

**Pentaho job**

[image]

**Error records in text file**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been solved this problem. It is my stupid mistake. I just recreate table and put more number for length of that column.

My case

post_name nvarchar(50) -> nvarchar(150)

Comment: How does Pentaho initialize the column's lengths when it creates a database? Is there a way to chose pertinent lengths automatically?